# How to paste a password in a field of web browser?

Tags: browser, password, copy-paste, password-protection

This question may look ridiculous at first look, but this is more sad than funny. In some cases, standart web browser (or any of the alternatives I tried - firefox, opera, dolphin) simply doesn't offer an option to paste anything in some text fields. But typing long complex password manually is deal breaker (hard to use keyboard + need to constantly switch apps back and forth unless I have super human abilities to remember all text at once)
How can I paste something in such cases?

Android version is 2.3.4

P.S. I'm already using Hacker's Keyboard, maybe it can help if text pasting can be done with some key combo? (like in most desktop OSes)

P.P.S. I know how to copy and paste text in *most* situations when a bunch of buttons appear after double press inside text field. The question is about the case when this doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try pressing and holding rather than the usual double tap? I'm referring to your *P.P.S*

Comment: oops, after long press a different menu appears and there is paste command

Comment: So my answer *is* correct n valid, Isn't it? YAY!! :)

Comment: @Sid yes, suddenly it is. :P

Comment: Seems like in android there is at least 2 different kinds of text fields which behave differently

Comment: > there are at least 2 different kinds... - slow fix. Sorry for sloppy English writing. (but I'm trying to improve it over time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply have the password typed in plain text. Keep it inside a sms conversation, e-mail, note, or anywhere you like. Nobody would know that is is your password since there is no indication to that matter in the place where the password is typed.

When you are required to type the password in your browser, just select all by pressing ald holding the typed text and copy it. Now go to the password field and touch and hold for a second or so and then a button named <kbd>paste</kbd> will appear. Then simply touch that button. The password will be pasted into the filed. Done!!

Comment: Sid, you missed the key part of the question: *simply doesn't offer an option to paste anything in some text fields*. So Sarge obviously knows about how to copy/paste generally -- but the apps in question don't permit him to.

Comment: @Izzy. Agree. Maybe... *just MAYBE* he is not clear of the way to do it. Isn't he?! Will see Sarges feedback n delete this if mine is useless. :)

Comment: From his phrasing, especially the *in some cases*, I think it's safe assuming he *is* aware of it (otherwise, why the restriction to "some cases"? That really *implies* there are "other cases" where it works). But allright, let's leave it to him to tell :)

Comment: Okay. Now I feel officially being laughed at. :(

Comment: *That* was not my intention -- apologies if I made you fell like that! But as agreed: Let's wait for the OP's statement (if he returns).

Comment: @Izzy is right, I know how to paste & copy in general. The question is about exceptional situations.

Comment: @Sid maybe you could mention a software such as (KeePassAndroid)[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.keepass&hl=en], which is much safer to use than an SMS... Now the _Hold for One Second_ was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

When you are using [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) you can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

Please note if you don't have a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, you can enable it in the keyboard's settings.

Comment: This doesn't work. (tried with text fields that allow pasting) Just types the 'V' or 'v' char. Tried both simultaneous press (multi touch) and sequential. What may I have done wrong?

Comment: You can give a shot to switching action in `Hacker Keyboard's Settings > Key behaviour settings > Ctrl key code` to `None(...)` or `Left Ctrl`.

Comment: shot given, no difference.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this link when I found an in-app password field that disallowed pasting.  I happen to use Lastpass that supplies an additional keyboard input method (press and hold space bar with the elipsis dots to switch input mode after configuring input methods).  I switched to that and it worked. Presumably other input keyboards have the ability to override default paste behavior. Good luck

Comment: This answer may be better with actual link to the application you are using (Lastpass) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for this answer, specifically for signing into Google using the Web Signin (Required if using secondary auth). For the password I just typed in a single letter then touching and holding the icon showed up for highlighting the text. Above it was the paste. I simply pasted my password, then deleted the first character.

Comment: Does not work for Android KitKat 4.4.2 (at least on my Moto G). [Here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/73200/22441)'s a much better solution that works for me.

Comment: Works for me on Lollipop and doesn't require installing a keyboard.