# How do I paste my password on Google Signin?

Tags: keyboard, 4.4-kitkat, password, copy-paste, authorization

I change the password of my Google account on a frequent basis. My password is always a quite long alphanumeric string generated by a password manager. Typing it is really annoying, specially on a touch interface, so usually I copy and paste it. It works in-browser, but **I can't use long pressing to copy and paste on the "Google Signin" screen**.

---

Let me be more clear. When I change it from the desktop web interface, a few moments later my phone complains about an "Account action required".

[image]

Clicking the notification shows me a (native, browserless) screen that says:

> Couldn't sign in: you typed an incorrect password or your account has changed. Re-type your password. If you forgot your password and need to recover your account click here.

[image]

Then it shows me another non-browser screen where it expects me to type my password. On this screen, I can paste as usual, by long-pressing near the cursor and then waiting for a "paste" button to apper.

[image]

So far, so good. However, I have two-factor authentication turned on, and just typing my password isn't enough. I see a second screen that says:

> Couldn't sign in: To access your account, you must sign in on the web. Touch Next to start Browser signin.

[image]

Then it opens what seems to be a browser-within-a-window, with my email address already typed and waiting for my password. The problem is, **I can't paste on this screen.** Long pressing does not show the "paste" button.

[image]

And if I trick it into showing me the button, then I can't submitting the password: I have followed [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/67367/22441) on a related question (writing a single characther and then long pressing), but then pressing the submit button produces no result at all.

Answer (score 4):

The trick here is to use a keyboard app with pasting ability. I had success using both [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) (It has a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> screen that you can combine with <kbd>v</kbd> to paste), and [Swype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.dtc) (long pressing on the <kbd>+!=</kbd> key and then in the four arrows key provides a screen where you can paste).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> and Swype (long pressing on the +!= key and then in the four arrows
>   key provides a screen where you can paste).

New

[image]